# abc PDF generate a blank page on IIS

Tags: asp.net, abcpdf

I am creating an PDF from HTML using ABC PDF 8.0, it works well on my local end but generate a blank page on IIS, I already down grade IE, and provide the all permission to folder. When I tried to generate the PDF through any external link like Google.com it works perfectly. more over my link is accessible and there is no error on the page.  please find below the code for your reference.

```
var url="test.com"
 if (XSettings.InstallLicense(abcPDFkey))
            {

                using (Doc theDoc = new Doc())
                {
                    //apply a rotation transform
                    double w = theDoc.MediaBox.Width;
                    double h = theDoc.MediaBox.Height;
                    double l = theDoc.MediaBox.Left;
                    double b = theDoc.MediaBox.Bottom;
                    theDoc.Transform.Rotate(90, l, b);
                    theDoc.Transform.Translate(w, 0);
                   // To fix time out
                    theDoc.HtmlOptions.RetryCount = 1;
                    theDoc.HtmlOptions.Timeout = 25000;


                    // rotate our rectangle
                    theDoc.Rect.Width = h;
                    theDoc.Rect.Height = w;
                    theDoc.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Gecko;
                    theDoc.HtmlOptions.ImageQuality = 60;
                    int theID;
                    theID = theDoc.AddImageUrl(url);
                    while (true)
                    {
                        theDoc.FrameRect();
                        if (!theDoc.Chainable(theID))
                            break;
                        theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
                        theID = theDoc.AddImageToChain(theID);
                        int NewtheID = theDoc.GetInfoInt(theDoc.Root, "Pages");
                        theDoc.SetInfo(NewtheID, "/Rotate", "90");
                    }
                    for (int i = 1; i <= theDoc.PageCount; i++)
                    {
                        theDoc.PageNumber = i;
                        theDoc.Flatten();
                    }
                    foreach (IndirectObject io in theDoc.ObjectSoup)
                    {
                        if (io is PixMap)
                        {
                            PixMap pm = (PixMap)io;
                            pm.Realize(); // eliminate indexed color images
                            pm.Resize(pm.Width / 6, pm.Height / 6);
                        }
                    }
                       theDoc.Save(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("PDFFileName"));
                    theDoc.Clear();
                }
```

Please help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what was the issue.

First of all I define the relative path for all my Images, and secondly Our server have internal IP, I define the URL for internal IP instead of public domain. that fix my issue..

cheers !!